# iOS - Change UICollectionView layout to fill rows instead of columns

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

Is it possible to change the UICollectionView so that it fills the rows instead of the columns ? Here's an image explaining it :

EDIT : It's an horizontal scroll

EDIT 2 : I already fits 3 cells in a row, my problem is that with 4 cells it doesn't fill the first row.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I had the exact same issue as you. Collectin view is horizontal & none-scrollable, but it was filling columns first.
Weirdly though, changing the direction to "Vertical" fixed the issue though!

Answer (score 0):

This takes me long hours of tries and finally what solved it was to change the scroll direction to vertical

```
layout.scrollDirection = .vertical //in case of horizontal collection

layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal //in case of vertical collection
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible.

1. Make sure the the collection view's width is equal to the screen
2. To have 3 cells on each row, you have to make sure the 3 cells will be able to fit the width of the screen.
3. Example: get the width of the screen & divided it by 3. Then set that value to the width of each cell. Also, for these three cells to fit in one row, the spacing between cells has to be zero. By doing that you have 3 cells that will fit exactly on the width of the screen for each row. if you want to add space between each cell, just divide the width of the screen by less than 3.

Comment: I'm already able to fit 3 cells in a row, it's just that it's filling the columns first. Please try with 4 cells you will see that iOS doesn't fill the first row.

Comment: Is it possible with horizontal scrolling ?